# MSSQL Query to compare and copy (sync) value from one column/table to another

Tags: sql-server

Can someone pls help me with this? I'm by no means a MSSQL expert and need to build this one-off query to do some kind of table-sync

I'm looking for a way to copy a value from one column in table A to another column in table B, based on the condition that the value doesn't allready exist in column B. And also remove values from table B if it doesn't exist in table A (again this is for the same column).

I have two tables that look like these (no inline posting of images yet):

dbo.EM_T_USERS

[image]

dbo.em_T_PRESENCE_USER_CONFIG

[image]

If you need any more information to answer just let me know...

Rgds,

David

- edit - added images for illustration of the tables

Comment: could you please share some sample SQL or just draw couple of tables with some sample records that shows your requirements?

Comment: thanks, I've added some sample screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that you are looking for :

```
DECLARE @Target TABLE (EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY, EmployeeName VARCHAR(10))

DECLARE @Source TABLE(EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY, EmployeeName VARCHAR(10));


INSERT @Target(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(100, 'Mary');
INSERT @Target(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(101, 'Sara');
INSERT @Target(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(102, 'Stefano');


INSERT @Source(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) Values(103, 'Bob');
INSERT @Source(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) Values(104, 'Steve');
INSERT @Source(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) Values(105, 'Sara');



MERGE @Target AS T
USING @Source AS S
ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' 
    THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%'
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;

SELECT * FROM @Target
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the tips and insights, however I have found a solution in setting up tiggers that when table A changes it will reflect those changes in table B.
Obviuously I haven't build those triggers myself, I've had some help from one of my collegues..

Rgds, David